# Save Changes in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, datagridview

After calling the table from the database into the dataGridView and entering data into the empty cells of this DataGridView, I want to save this data to my database by clicking on the button, but I don’t know how to do this

This is how I access db:

```
public MySqlConnection mycon;
 public MySqlCommand mycom;
 public string connect = "Server=localhost;Database=base;Uid=root;password=pas;charset=utf8";
 public SD.DataSet ds;

 mycon = new MySqlConnection(connect);
 mycon.Open();

 MySqlDataAdapter ms_data = new MySqlDataAdapter(script, connect);
 SD.DataTable table = new SD.DataTable();
 ms_data.Fill(table);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
 mycon.Close();
```

Comment: There are many, many fine examples on how to use those tools hidden in [The Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/).  Configuring them properly, it should just be `MySqlDataAdapter.Update();`.  Likewise, there are many examples on this very site as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pains me to write it, but this should be the minimum set of calls necessary:

```
MySqlDataAdapter ms_data = new MySqlDataAdapter(script, connect);
new MySqlCommandBuilder(ms_data);
ms_data.Update(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable);
```

You need an adapter, and then passing it to a command builder should make the CB read the select command loaded into the adapter and use it to populate the adapter's other commands (insert/update/delete), then you can call Update and pass a modified table and the rows in the table will be examined to see if they're new, modified or deleted and the appropriate command will be called to persist the changes

`script` needs to be an SQL that selects the primary key columns from the DB

---

Why "pains to say it" ? Because it's such a long winded, hard work way of doing database access compared to even the technology that replaced it, let alone something modern like EF. If you're liking working with datatables, consider:

- Add a new DataSet type of file to the project
- Open it, right click the surface, add a tableadapter
- Configure the connection string
- Configure a "select that returns rows" query like `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = @someId`
- A tableadapter and datatable pair appear, that mimick the table in the database
- Switch to a form, open the data sources window (View Menu, Other Windows), drag the table to the form - a datagridview, dataset, tableadapter, navigator etc appear.
- Everything is wired up to go.

Your tableadapter is a dataadapter on steroids, and will Fill/Update the datatable from/to database. The datatable has named columns and is generally much nicer to work with. All the code for loading and saving is already written into the FormX.cs so you can take a look, but it basically amounts to:

```
var x = new BlahBlahTableAdapter();
x.FillBy(this.BlahBlahDataSet, someIdTextBox.Text);
```

Filling the datatable that is binded to the grid will cause the data to appear in the grid automatically.

Saving is similarly simple:

```
var x = new BlahBlahTableAdapter();
x.Update(this.BlahBlahDataSet);
```

---

Footnote: I believe you need MySQL Tools For Visual Studio installed for this to play nice. Also, you might encounter issues if you made a NetCore/Net5+ WinForms project because some elements of new .NET don't support winforms properly

Footnote2: See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99199 if you're wondering why the tableadapter wizard option "Refresh the dataset" is not working

---

If you want to try something more modern, there are lots of good EF tutorials out there. EF is a tool that uses a database to create objects in your code. The data for the objects lives in the database and is automatically transported back and forth from/to objects/database by EF. If you get into it, EF Core Power Tools is a very useful VS addin to have

Comment: This is such a great answer! but i got an issue, when i press button it only saves the filled cells and this is right, but i have some cells that filled by the triggers and they just stay empty, what can i do?

Comment: What does "filled by the triggers" mean? You have triggers in the database that calculate some values?

Comment: Yes! thats it! but those triggers arent working in this method as i can see. The cells that should be calculated by the triggers just stay empty after update, i also have "generated column" function and its actually working well

Comment: The easiest approach is to go the third way (EF) because that's automatic. Next easiest is the second way I noted (add a dataset..) - There's a mysql bug to work around but by and large it will be a lot simpler; you basically have to query the database again after you do the insert. Mysql has a last_insert_id() helper that will allow you to retrieve the row that was just inserted. You can do this manually yourself too but it's the next level up in terms of hassle

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use "last_insert_id()" in my situation? In this or new question page, i have to do this programm untill tomorrow so i doubt i can learn an EF today to do this task

Comment: I've never done it manually. I'd say have a go at doing way 2 (dataset) then you can look in dataset.Designer.cs and find the code it's written and copy it if you still want. I'm installing mysql to have a play with it but if you get desperate, just re-run your code that loaded the grid first time round; reloading from the db will make the calculated values show up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241506/discussion-between-xto-and-caius-jard).

Comment: It looks like doing `ms_data.InsertCommand.CommandText += "; SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE idxxx = LAST_INSERT_ID();` after the MySQlCommandBuilder line might be all that is required. Of course, you should change the xxx to the table name and idxxx to the primary key column name

Comment: If that appears not to work, check the value of UpdatedRowSource of the InsertCommand on the adapter - it should be FirstReturnedRow or Both

Comment: could you please tell me how to check the value of UpdatedRowSource, cant find how to use "updatedRowSource" i only have found `public System.Data.UpdateRowSource UpdatedRowSource { get; set; }`

Comment: Like `ms_data.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRow`

Comment: It's finally inserting something! but for some reason it inserts only a couple of values, the rest of cells staying empty and it still gives me `object reference not set to an instance of an object` every time i press the button, but it insert something at least!

Comment: So, the cells that are populated, are they the non-database generated ones? And the DB generated ones are blank?

Comment: I tried the table that doesnt have any generated columns and after adding some values into the cells it only saves some of them, all the others stay empty and it gives me `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: When you say "saves", you mean you type something into every editable column, and then lick save, and when you qury the DB with e.g. MySQLWorkbench, only some of the things you typed are saved in the DB table?

Comment: Yes! Thats it! And it is also always gives me an error `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: I'm not so much bothered about the null ref exception; it's easy enough to solve. The data not making it into the database sounds like the insert statement doesn't have all the columns from the local datatable mapped. Can you tell me, just before you run the `.Update`, what the value of `ms_data.InsertCommand.CommandText` statement actually is?

Comment: If you mean my code in Button_click to insert the data its `ms_data.Update(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable);
                ms_data.InsertCommand.CommandText += "select * from rabt where id = last_insert_id();";
                ms_data.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;`

Comment: I meant to pause the code in the debugger and look at what the insert command is; you're complkaining that some values are not being inserted so we have to start diagnosing why. My first port of call would be "are they even in the INSERT statement"

Comment: To pause when i add some values into the dataGridView but before i click the insert button?

Comment: When the code is running. You know how to use the debugger? (Press F9 on some line with code, it goes red, visual studio will stop with a yellow bar on that line when the program is running and it *wanted* to run that line, then you can point your mouse at variables to see their value, and press F10 or F11 to advance the yellow bar one step at a time

Comment: I tried this now and if i point on `ms_data` and it is not yellow it says `null` and if the string with `ms_data"` is yellow it says `{MySqlConnector.MySqlDataAdapter}`

Comment: So you can expand it.. But it sounds like you've never used the debugger- I'd recommend watching some YouTube tutorials on it or something as explaining everything in comments will take long and be more confusing than watching it in a video. Tim Corey's stuff is easy to understand and clear. What is the value of the InsertCommand commandText?

Comment: it says `Container = null, DeleteCommand (System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter) = null, DeleteCommand = null, InsertCommand (System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter) = null, InsertCommand` and if i expand any of those it says `EventDisposed = {object}`

Comment: I gonna check some videos then! Thanks!

Comment: When i point on ms_data.InsertCommand i get `instance = {MySqlConnector.Logging.NoOpLogger}`

Comment: Change the line `new MySqlCommandBuilder(ms_data);` to `var cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(ms_data);` F10 the yellow bar over it, and then in the immediate window write `cb.GetInsertCommand()` - what CommandText shows there?

Comment: I can tell you that im just dumb... those values didnt insert because they were in `' '` in my `script` string but i always inserted numbers and now they can be inserted as i have removed `' '`, in the table where i dont have any triggers and generated columns at least, but i still get `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: So, you can use the debugger to find out what is null. Somewhere in your code you have `something.OtherThing` and the *something* is `null` when you point to it

Comment: For now it says `ms_data.InsertCommand` is `null`, not sure this is the case so i will try to find something else

Comment: I think i fixed this, i had to write  `cb.GetInsertCommand();`  and then `ms_data.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();` and now there is no null reference exception